# How do I prevent Nest.js from logging an exception to the console?

Tags: exception, graphql, nestjs, apollo-server

**Background**

We use `ApolloHandler` to handle the exceptions in our Nest.js + GraphQL application.

**Problem**

Although `ApolloHandler` manages to create a structured GraphQL error response, every exception (plus it stack trace) also generates a console log and a logger entry `[ExceptionHandler]`, polluting the application log with thousands of already managed input errors.

**Question**

How to set Nest.js to supress those `ApolloHandler` exceptions? Of course non `ApolloHandler` exceptions should remain logged.

Comment: There is an issue for this https://github.com/nestjs/graphql/issues/2060

Answer (score -2):

Create your own custom logger to filter out those messages like:

```
export class AppLogger extends Logger {

  error(message: string, trace: string, context?: string) {
    if (message !== 'Validations failed!') {
      super.error(message, trace, context)
    }
  }

}
```

And use it as

```
app.useLogger(new AppLogger())
```